# Error while saving an entity with transient property with spring data neo4j

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Why is spring-data looking at `isCaptain` even when I specified it as `transient`? From the documentation, the `transient` properties should be ignored. No error if I use a `Boolean` wrapper class

Exception

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Setting property isCaptain to null on Player [nodeId=1, name=null, firstName=null, lastName=null]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.setProperty(SourceStateTransmitter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(SourceStateTransmitter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(SourceStateTransmitter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:240)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesFrom(SourceStateTransmitter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.loadEntity(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:244)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.save(AbstractGraphRepository.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.aravind.avl.domain.PlayerRepositoryTest.firstNameExactMatchOnly(PlayerRepositoryTest.java:53)
```

ENTITY

```
@NodeEntity
public class Player
{
    @GraphId
    private Long nodeId;

    @GraphProperty
    @Indexed
    private String firstName;

    @GraphProperty
    @Indexed
    private String lastName;

    private transient boolean isCaptain;
}
```

JUNIT

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "/testContext.xml" })
@Transactional
public class PlayerRepositoryTest
{
    @Autowired
    PlayerRepository repo;

    Player p;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        p = new Player();
        p.setName("Aravind Yarram");
    }

    @Test
    public void firstNameFullTextSearch()
    {
        Player save = repo.save(p);
        assertNotNull(save);
        assertNotNull(p.getNodeId());

        EndResult<Player> players = repo.findAllByQuery("firstName", "A*");
        assertNotNull("Starts with first letter match", players.single());

        // TODO not supported
        // players = repo.findAllByQuery("firstName", "aravind");
        // assertNotNull("Lower-case mathch", players.single());
    }

    @Test
    public void firstNameExactMatchOnly()
    {
        Player save = repo.save(p);
        assertNotNull(save);
        assertNotNull(p.getNodeId());

        // either use domain specific method
        Player result = repo.findByPropertyValue("firstName", p.getFirstName());
        assertNotNull("findByPropertyValue should be used for EXACT matches", result);

        // or generic method
        result = repo.findPlayerByFirstName(p.getFirstName());
        assertNotNull("Exact mathch", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've posted an abridged version of the Player so not to make the post long. I removed the name property.

Comment: Good, so that's out of the picture. Have you tried with the `@Transient` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transient` as suggested by *Sotirios Delimanolis* works. I believe the `transient` keyword isn't honored because it can conflict with use-cases where Serialization is required. For e.g. you might want the `isCaptain` property to be available in web session but not required to be saved to the neo4j, my exact situation.